# Need help of step by step calculation for unbiasedness of Ordinary Least Square?

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, unbiased-estimator

How exactly can I go from the top blue to the bottom blue equation in the blue box of the picture below. I have marked the part with red arrow. The lecturer says that we can go from the top blue to the bottom blue equation using zero conditional mean, in other words, errors are independent of $x_i$.

Why does the Expectation pass through $(xi−\bar{x})$? Is it treated as a number? The lecturer said $u_i$ given $x_i$. I think what he said was the covariance between $x_i$ and $u_i$, which means $x_i$ and $u_i$ is independent. Does it mean that $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$? And the expectation of $u_i$ is $0$ and the whole left part of the plus sign in the equation becomes zero?

Hope the image is clear to understand the question and to hear some explanations. Some specific calculation will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this qualify as [tag:self-study]? If so, please add the tag and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: What have you done so far in trying to solve the problem? Do you have any ideas how the "red arrow" works?

Comment: Why does the Expectation pass through $(x_i - \bar{x})$? The lecturer said $u_i$ given $x_i$. I think what he said was the covariance between $x_i$ and $u_i$, which means $x_i$ and $u_i$ is independent. Does it mean that $Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)$? And the expectation of $u_i$ is $0$ and the whole left part of the plus sign in the equation becomes zero?

Comment: Just include that in the question, it is how the `self-study` questions work.